# Is it possible to limit the number of instances of a class at compile time?

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, object-construction

Assume there is a class `Foo` that I, as the designer of a library, do not want my users to be able to instantiate more than `n` amount of times (where `n` is not necessarily `1`).
Is there any way to enforce this rule **during compilation**?

Please note that I am not after a Singleton or likewise pattern, as I would like the users to realize they should not instantiate the class, *before* executing their code.

So far, my best attempt was a combination of `static_assert` and the `__COUNTER__` macro but to no avail as they do not seem to be evaluated, as I'd expect, inside functions or classes.

```
constexpr int bar()
{
    static_assert( __COUNTER__ < 5, "You called this too many times!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This kind of check cannot be done at compile time, only at runtime. If you don't want to use a singleton, make the counter be a static member of the class, increment the counter in the constructor, and have the constructor throw an exception once the counter has been exceeded.

Comment: Yeah, I am afraid it is as you say... It is a little disappointing because looking at `static_assert` and `__COUNTER__` seemed like the building blocks for such a solution could be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Even leaving aside the fact that a single function making a single instance could be called multiple times, or that instantiation could occur in a loop or template, nothing could stop instantiation from occurring in another *translation unit*.